# In MySQL can I create a view of the rows with the highest number from one field?

Tags: mysql, view

I have a view with

```
   SELECT
downs_history_2022.`Asset Id`,
downs_history_2022.Email,
downs_history_2022.`User Id`,
downs_history_2022.`Log Date`,
downs_history_2022.Downloaded,
downs_history_2022.`month`,
downs_history_2022.`year`,
ldapfull_kf.mail,

FROM
downs_history_2022
INNER JOIN ldapfull_kf ON downs_history_2022.`User Id` = ldapfull_kf.uid
```

Month is a single or two digit field 1-12.    I save everything in a historical table and would like to extract the "last month's" data into a view.    Meaning if I last extracted June into the historical data I would like the view to be month = 6... but I don't want to have to go change this every month.  (I know I could just create a table with month and year and change those fields in that one table to join but was wondering if I could skip that)

Comment: Provide: precise MySQL version (output for `SELECT VERSION();`), sample data (textual code-formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) and desired view output for this data.

Comment: How many rows does the view return?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE VIEW ...`  Where is the `WHERE` clause that specifies the year and month?  On the `SELECT` that calls the view?  Then let's see that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a VIEW is just a shorthand for a SELECT.  If you can write a SELECT, you can create a VIEW.

Plan A:  Save the "6" in a separate, one-line< table.

Plan B:  Write a SELECT (perhaps as a subquery in the VIEW you are hypothecating).  It would do something `SELECT MAX(month) FROM ...`.

You will probably find that it is messy to have Year and Month in separate columns.  (But that is another discussion.)

Comment: I tried that and only got one row - obviously doing it incorrectly.   I added more context in my question.   Appreciate your help as always.    Also month and year have been surprisingly nice to have in different columns.    From a front end perspective we can let users choose month and year separate and fast...  but maybe that is because I am a lazy gui programmer!